# phonegap authenticate on remote website and access its content

Tags: authentication, cordova

How can I access content of a website within the PhoneGap WebView?

My application accesses a website with a login form. I want to grab & parse the resulting credentials/content displayed in the website.

Using the ChildBrowser Plugin, it seems that I don't have any access to the child browsers content?

Thanks in advance
Max

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at XMLHttpRequest? You should be able to use that in your JavaScript to request the page.

Comment: hey, thanks, the problem ist that the user should first login on that page, then submit something on the next and than the page appears with the needed data. i'm now using the child browser plugin and letting that user copy the value and then letting im insert it into a textfield in my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jQuery's [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function for that!